# Set none selected in Winforms TreeView component

Tags: c#, winforms

Initially, I want nothing selected on my TreeView. By default, the first node is selected/focused.The code

```
treeView1.SelectedNode = null;
```

didn't work.

Comment: You need to call `treeView1.Focus()` for the appearance to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tree node is not selected but has tap stop

```
treeView1.SelectedNode = null;
treeView1.TabStop = false;
```

Comment: While this works, the user loses the ability to navigate to the control using the keyboard.

Comment: @SSS The tree element is not selected, but has focus. You should remove it by focusing on another element. As an example if there a textbox in your form, you may use textBox1.Select();

Comment: What I meant is that, with this solution, the user can no longer navigate to the treeview using the TAB key

Answer (score 0):

Put your line of code

```
treeView1.SelectedNode = null;
```

in the `Form.Shown` event, rather than in the `Form.Load` event. The default selection occurs after `Form.Load`, so you want to clear the selection after that.

Answer (score 0):

Put your line of code

```
TreeView.HideSelection = false;
```